# Create new event from another one in Javascript NOT byRef (ie7 compatible)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events

I'm trying to create a new object (event) in my javascript code from an another event (window.event). I would like to create this one new event byVal e not byRef because i need this event also window.event were dead.
This code must be ie7 compatible.

I tryied this but doesn't work :-(

```
function copyMyEvent(p) {
  if (!p) throw Error('no type');
  function f() {};
  f.prototype = p;
  return new f();
};

var event = copyMyEvent( window.event );
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but you might want to stringify and then re-evaluate the code to make this happen. You should try some of the polyfills for deep object copy.

Check this question:
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)